# cakephp 2.3.x or PHP need to rename all video files in a directory - getting error

Tags: php, file, cakephp, video, rename

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.1 on a MAMP server on Mac OSX.  I am having trouble when I try to use rename($oldname, $newname); because I always get the following error:

FATAL ERROR

Error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9662464 bytes)
File: /Users/esjenkins/Sites/cakephp/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp
Line: 56

I tried setting the permissions on the folder to everyone read/write.

If I comment out the rename($oldname, $newname); I can get an echo as I would expect for those two variables in each loop.  As an Example:

$oldname = /Users/esjenkins/Sites/cakephp/app/webroot/files/asdfasf2929.mp4

$newname = /Users/esjenkins/Sites/cakephp/app/webroot/files/2929.mp4

Here is the PHP code in my View folder file called list_adjudication.ctp

```
<div class="dances index">
    <h3><?php echo 'Adjudication Files'; ?></h3>
    <?php
    $adjudication_path = APP . 'webroot/files/'; 
    if ($handle = opendir($adjudication_path)) {

        /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && $entry != ".DS_Store" && $entry != "empty") {
            $adj_file_string = "$entry\n"; 
                //echo $adj_file_string . " <br /> <br /> ";
                $rename_adj_file_string = substr($adj_file_string, -9, 8);
                //echo $rename_adj_file_string . " <br /> <br /> ";
                $oldname = $adjudication_path . $adj_file_string;
                $newname = $adjudication_path . $rename_adj_file_string;
                echo $oldname . " | " . $newname . " <br /> <br /> "; 
                rename($oldname, $newname);
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

I have about 750 adjudication files that I will need renamed after upload.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Trying to rename in a loop doesn't work (per thaJeztah's advice below).  I was able to successfully use the rename($oldname, $newname); outside of the loop.  I will experiment more with putting the file names into an array and I will report the results later.

ANSWER: I couldn't get rename() to work in any loop, even with the use of an array for some reason.  But I did get things working by putting this code into the controller:

```
public function list_adjudication() {
    $adjudication_path = APP . 'webroot/files/';
    $dir = new Folder($adjudication_path);
    $files = $dir->find('.*\.mp4');
    //print_r($files);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        //$file = new File($dir->pwd() . DS . $file);
        echo $file . " <br /> ";  
        //$contents = $file->read();
        // // $file->write('I am overwriting the contents of this file');
        // // $file->append('I am adding to the bottom of this file.');
        // // $file->delete(); // I am deleting this file
    $newName = substr($file, -8, 8);
    //echo $newName; exit;
    rename($adjudication_path . $file, $adjudication_path . $newName); 
    }
        //$file->close(); // Be sure to close the file when you're done
}
```

I'm not sure if it's ok to have this code in the Controller or if it would be proper to put it in the Model.  I'm super new to CakePHP and coding in general.  As soon as I get past a major deadline I'm going to go back and try learning the blog tutorial from scratch to get a better grasp of the basics.

HUGE THANKS to @thaJeztah for helping to AGAIN get over a major hurdle.  Save my butt again.  Many thanks.

Comment: Is this the *only* thing happening in your view/controller? Are the files actually renamed at all? What happens of you just rename a single file, *not* inside the loop?

Comment: Just wondering if renaming *inside* the loop can cause problems because renaming the file will affect the position of other files in the directory (e.g. File1 was first, but becomes the second file after renaming it). You may try to collect all file names in an array *first* and then loop over the array and rename each file

Comment: I don't think there is anything going in my controller of relevance but I'll post my Controller after I experiment a bit more.  I like your approach of trying to rename outside of the loop.  I was able to successfully rename outside of the loop with   rename('/Users/esjenkins/Sites/cakephp/app/webroot/files/aqwer1420.mp4', '/Users/esjenkins/Sites/cakephp/app/webroot/files/1420.mp4'); I'm going to keep experimenting for a bit more and see what else I can figure out.  Renaming inside the loop is probably the problem.  I'm going to try your advice of collecting the file names in an array first.

Comment: This code is completely inappropriate to put in a view file.

Comment: @AD7six that would be my next suggestion, but I tried to keep it focused to the problem itself first :o) Also, using the [Folder Utility](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html) probably is more CakePHP as well..

Comment: I gave up on trying to get the rename() to work in a loop.  I tried it with an array but for some reason I just could not get rename() to work when it was in a loop BUT I did use some features from Folder Utility per @thaJeztah and I got it working by putting code into the controller!  I'm pretty freakn' happy about that so thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Increase memory_limit in php.ini

you can increase memory limit several way,

1. directly php.ini file,

   memory_limit = 2048M
2. via .htaccess

   php_value memory_limit 2048M
3. or use

   ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

in your application.

Comment: There is no php.ini I can find in CakePHP.  I'm only trying to rename 5 files to start.  Shouldn't be any memory issue I don't think.

Comment: It is in your php folder, where php has installed in you mac.

Comment: Getting a memory exhaustion on such a simple piece of code is a warning that *something is wrong*. Blindly increasing the memory limit is a *bad* suggestion in such case! Also, if you read the error message; the current memory limit is 32MB which should be more than enough for most cases